# https on S3 WITHOUT cloudfront possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

We currently want to start hosting all our assets through AWS S3 and we also want to server everything over https. I understand I can use the Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM) with Cloudfront to server assets over https. The problem is that we are in the medical industry and we are legally prohibited to host anything outside the EU. With S3 I can choose a location (Frankfurt for us), but with Cloudfront I just get this option:

[image]

So I thought that I could maybe use Letsencrypt to generate my own certs. But I think I then still need to use ACM which only works with Cloudfront, which means I still can't use it.

Does anybody know if I can somehow setup S3 with https but *without* cloudfront?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use an SSL certificate with your custom domain with S3. You can use the S3 domain with the Amazon SSL certificate like: `https://my-example-bucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.

If you want to use a custom domain with SSL, and you can't use CloudFront, then you will need to look into placing some other proxy in front of S3 like your own Nginx server or something.

Comment: Ah, a proxy for it. That is a great idea! I guess I'm going for that

Comment: @kramer65 You could also look into other CDNs instead of CloudFront if there is a CDN that meets your business requirements.

Comment: Yes I'm also lloking into that. If you've got any tips for a CDN in which I can choose the hosting locations that would be very welcome

Comment: Am I correct that as of June 2018, https for my-example-bucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com no longer works? It looks like its now only available on http?

Comment: This answer is outdated. You can now certainly use SSL Certificate with Custom domains with S3 along with Route53 and Cloudfront. The SSL Certificate can be requested from Certificate Manager for free.

Comment: @Annjawn all of that is addressed in the original question. The original question states that they don't want to use CloudFront.

Comment: @MarkB I dont think SSL wildcard was ever available for `s3-website`, but it certainly is available for s3 REST endpoints (as long as bucket name does not have `.` in its name)

Comment: There is a note under the section "Amazon Simple Storage Service Website Endpoints" in <https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html>, stating "The website endpoints do not support https.". So, those s3-website endpoints do not support HTTPS anymore.

Comment: The statement "Amazon S3 website endpoints do not support HTTPS. " has been moved to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteEndpoints.html

Answer (score 5):

In AWS **API Gateway**, you can create a *proxy* resource `/{proxy+}` that maps to `s3-website`.

Be sure to map not to `s3` alone, but `s3-website`, so you get `PATH/TO/DIR/index.html` returned for `PATH/TO/DIR`, and possibly other things working as desired.

API Gateway is served over HTTPS, optionally under your own domain.

This is not very good option though, because you have to manually add all allowed HTTP return codes, and there's a limit of 10MB payload in a request, as this service is aimed at REST APIs.

Comment: API gateway isn't actually any cheaper that CloudFront.  Besides being a hacky solution, you can't connect to API gateway by http.  Since most browsers default to http if no protocol is given, this causes a bad experience.  CloudFront can redirect http to https.  If you're using API gateway for an API that is great.  But for a html website, use CloudFront or a non-aws service.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a useful resource schedule.  Both S3 and CloudFront are available in the EU.  You can certainly present S3 via CloudFront.

I understand the requirements to host within a territorial boundary. The req'ts for that you will achieve with S3 in the EU region.  CloudFront is not a hosting service it is a CDN (Content Delivery network) using high performance leased lines and manageable endpoint caching.  The issue you are looking at is the price options, not the hosting location.  If you want to serve content in the EU you would want 'Price Class 100' or 'Price Class All'.

When using CloudFront you can control both which IP ranges that can access your material, and the encryption of both front-end and back-end traffic. Check out some of the design patterns

There are some excellent white papers and design patterns for setting up secure CloudFront. I think you will find that you can do what you want and stay well within the legal requirements.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region
https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/eu-data-protection/

Also check out AWS doco 'using-https-cloudfront-to-s3-origin' & 'custom-ssl-domains'

P.S.   Ensure that you set the bucket permissions to only be available via the CloudFront channel.

RL

Answer (score 1):

CloudFront has a feature for white/blacklisting countries.  I would try using any of the 3 CDN options you listed along with a whitelist of EU countries.  I'm not sure what the easiest way to verify that other countries (e.g. US) are denied though.