# Are S3 static websites no longer available over HTTPS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've got a static S3 website. When I log in, I can see that the endpoint is `http://www.example.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com`, but I've seen [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441828/https-on-s3-without-cloudfront-possible) claiming that the site should be accessible via HTTPS at `https://www.example.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com`. This doesn't work though.

Did AWS used to support HTTPS for static sites and have now stopped it, or do I need to enable it somehow?

Comment: You need a CloudFront distribution to serve your S3 content over HTTPS. Use ACM to request the certificate.

Comment: I've already done that. I want to encrypt between CloudFront and the S3 bucket itself.

Comment: AFAIK, S3 doesn't support **custom-domain** HTTPS to serve static files directly. You may access the standard URL using HTTPS though. If you're using the S3 API, then you may use it via HTTPS.

Comment: But this isn't a custom domain. This is the S3-assigned domain.

Comment: I mean, if you had `www-example-com` (no periods in the bucket name), Amazon's wildcard certificate would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer is no, it's not possible to use HTTPS for S3 static websites directly like I'm trying to do. From [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-cloudfront-to-s3-origin.html):

> Note the following about using HTTPS when the origin is an Amazon S3
>   bucket:
>
> ```
> * If your Amazon S3 bucket is configured as a website endpoint, you can't 
> configure CloudFront to use HTTPS to communicate with your
> origin because Amazon S3 doesn't support HTTPS connections in that
> configuration.
> ```

Answer (score 5):

The [website hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) section on S3 now has this note at the bottom of the page:

> The Amazon S3 website endpoints do not support HTTPS. For information about using HTTPS with an Amazon S3 bucket, see [How do I use CloudFront to serve HTTPS requests for my Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3) and [Requiring HTTPS for Communication Between CloudFront and Your Amazon S3 Origin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-cloudfront-to-s3-origin.html).

Seems the only option now is to use CloudFront. Quite disappointing when you just want a quick and dirty HTTPS website and would happily use `https://examplebucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/` as the URL, which would work fine with a wildcard SSL certificate.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use periods in the bucket name. If you do use periods, Amazon's wildcard certificate won't work.

Quoting the [BucketRestrictions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html) documentation:

> When you use virtual hosted–style buckets with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL), the SSL wildcard certificate only matches buckets that don't contain periods. To work around this, use HTTP or write your own certificate verification logic. We recommend that you do not use periods (".") in bucket names when using virtual hosted–style buckets.

Comment: This isn't about the validity of certificates. I get no response when I try to make an https request to the bucket.

Comment: I'm not talking about validity when I say it won't work. But you're right, I should reword it.